# Loading and executing ELF-64 object code--unsure about the last steps

Tags: c, loader, elf

I'm writing a small tool for experimenting with ELF-64 object code which is intended to parse and load ELF-64 object code for execution in the parent process. I believe I'm on the right track for now, but I need some pointers for the last steps.

**Step 1:** I parse the object file and extract all necessary information. I've verified this to be correct using the `readelf` tool.

**Step 2:** I loop through all section headers with the `SHF_ALLOC`-bit set and `mmap` memory.

**Step 3:** This seemingly simple and useless object consisting of only a `main`-routine and a return statement, requires no symbol relocating as far as I know (I've double-checked with `readelf`). I've compiled with TinyCC to avoid `.eh_frame` and its relocation entries from being emitted.

But at this point I need to load the sections with `SHF_ALLOC`-bit set into memory, and this is where I suspect I'm doing wrong.

```
offset = 0

foreach section in sections
    if section.flags & SHF_ALLOC
        memcpy(memory_address + offset, object_code + section.offset, section.size)
        offset += section_size
```

**Step 4:** The last step which I'm unsure of also. I need to call into the allocated memory which I've marked as executable.

```
typedef int (main_t)(int argc, char* argv[]);

((main_t)object->address)(0, NULL);
```

I'd very much appreciate some input on this. I believe it boils down to lack of understanding what exactly `.text`-segment contains and how they are intended to be stored in memory.

Some thoughts:

- is `main` located at offset `0x0` in the `.text`-segment?
- are allocated segments intended to be stored sequentially with the right alignments?

Anything to point me in the right direction will help immensely! Thanks!

PS. I intend to learn about relocating symbols shortly. One step at a time. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to pull this off after a good night's sleep.

I first disassembled the object file using `objdump` which produced:

```
/tmp/test.o:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000000000 <main>:
   0:   55                      push   %rbp
   1:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
   4:   48 81 ec 10 00 00 00    sub    $0x10,%rsp
   b:   48 89 7d f8             mov    %rdi,-0x8(%rbp)
   f:   48 89 75 f0             mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
  13:   b8 c8 00 00 00          mov    $0xc8,%eax
  18:   e9 00 00 00 00          jmpq   1d <main+0x1d>
  1d:   c9                      leaveq 
  1e:   c3                      retq
```

This output ensured me the location of `main` to be at `0x0`, meaning if I copy the `.text`-segment correctly into memory at the address returned by `mmap`, I should be able to call it with the snippet found in the question (which I was unsure about). It'll use the stack of the calling thread.

I then found a small error when copying the sections to memory where `section.offset` was the offset from the beginning of the **file**, which I mistakenly assumed was the offset from the beginning of the section header entry.

It'll be much simpler to experiment when I know the basics work. :-)

Answer (score 2):

You should use program headers for that, not section headers. Section headers are for the linker, program headers are for the loader.

Allocated segments are intended to go to their preferred `VirtAddr`, if they have one (non-prelinked libraries may have a base virtual address of 0, which means the loader will assign them random addresses).

The ELF header has an entry point field. This is not `main`, it's typically some libc initialization code that ... does initialization ... and then calls `main`. You should have setup everything conforming to the ELF ABI prior to passing control to the entry point (put `argc`, `argv`, `envp`, `auxv` on the stack, clear some registers, I think that's it).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. While it may seem my question was overly fixated on loading object code through the section headers for whatever perverse reasons, I managed to pull this off. Details can be found in my answer. Next step is more complex object code... :-)